# Reading and appending files context manager: Doesn't seem to read, only writes

Tags: python, web-scraping, contextmanager, beautifulsoup

I am trying to read and append to a file but when I am using context manager it doesn't seem to work.

In this code I am trying to get all links on a site that contain one of the items in my 'serien' list. If the link is in the list, I am first checking whether the link is already in the file. If the link is found, it is supposed to not append the link again. But it does.

I am either guessing that I am not using the right mode or that I somehow screwed up with my context manager. Or am I completely wrong

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


serien = ['izombie', 'grandfathered', 'new-girl']
serien_links = []


#Gets chapter links
def episode_links(index_url):
    r = requests.get(index_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    links = soup.find_all('a')
    url_list = []
    for url in links:
        url_list.append((url.get('href')))
    return url_list

urls_unfiltered = episode_links('http://watchseriesus.tv/last-350-posts/')
with open('link.txt', 'a+') as f:
    for serie in serien:
        for x in urls_unfiltered:
            #check whether link is already in file. If not write link to file
            if serie in x and serie not in f.read():
                f.write('{}\n'.format(x))
```

This is my first time using context managers. Tips would be appreciated.

Edit: Similar project without context manager. Here I also tried using context managers but gave up after I had the same problem.

```
file2_out = open('url_list.txt', 'a') #local url list for chapter check
for x in link_list:
    #Checking chapter existence in folder and downloading chapter
    if x not in open('url_list.txt').read(): #Is url of chapter in local url list?
        #push = pb.push_note(get_title(x), x)
        file2_out.write('{}\n'.format(x)) #adding downloaded chapter to local url list
        print('{} saved.'.format(x))


file2_out.close()
```

And with context manager:

```
with open('url_list.txt', 'a+') as f:
    for x in link_list:
        #Checking chapter existence in folder and downloading chapter
        if x not in f.read(): #Is url of chapter in local url list?
            #push = pb.push_note(get_title(x), x)
            f.write('{}\n'.format(x)) #adding downloaded chapter to local url list
            print('{} saved.'.format(x))
```

Comment: You say this fails when you're using a context manager, did you previously have a working version without this? If so please show that code.

Comment: Added code of similar project without context manager

Comment: The first time `f.read()` is called it reads the whole file, and then after that it gets and empty string. Try reading the whole file and storing it into a variable and then check its contents over-and-over in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @martineau mentioned `f.read()` reads the whole file and then gets empty string. try the below code. it reads the contents to list and later comparisons happens on the list.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

serien = ['izombie', 'grandfathered', 'new-girl']
serien_links = []


# Gets chapter links
def episode_links(index_url):
    r = requests.get(index_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    links = soup.find_all('a')
    url_list = []
    for url in links:
        url_list.append((url.get('href')))
    return url_list


urls_unfiltered = episode_links('http://watchseriesus.tv/last-350-posts/')
with open('link.txt', 'a+') as f:
    cont = f.read().splitlines()
    for serie in serien:
        for x in urls_unfiltered:
            # check whether link is already in file. If not write link to file
            if (serie in x) and (x not in cont):
                f.write('{}\n'.format(x))
```